# Website user input post to a file in my pc

Tags: php, html

I need help with a php program. I cant find the problem
This is the code I came up with. I just have multiple user inputs and I need the php code to put those inputs in a file.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
$discord = $_POST['discord'];
$adress = $_POST['adress'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$W1 = $_POST['W1'];
$W2 = $_POST['W2'];
$W3 = $_POST['W3'];

$file = fopen("userinput.txt","a+") or die ("file not open");

$s = $name. "," .$discord."," .$adress."," .$age."," .$W1."," .$W2."," .$W3.",\n";
fputs($file,$s) or die ("Data not write");

fclose($file);
}
?><?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
$discord = $_POST['discord'];
$adress = $_POST['adress'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$W1 = $_POST['W1'];
$W2 = $_POST['W2'];
$W3 = $_POST['W3'];

$file = fopen("userinput.txt","a+") or die ("file not open");

$s = $name. "," .$discord."," .$adress."," .$age."," .$W1."," .$W2."," .$W3.",\n";
fputs($file,$s) or die ("Data not write");

fclose($file);
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to show a specific problem like an error or an unwanted behaviours of your code. It's difficult to help you otherwise.

Comment: what exact issue are you having with the code? Please report how it behaves when you run it, and what inputs you gave it. Also please ensure you have error reporting switched on in PHP, so you can tell us about any error messages / warnings it generates. Right now, you haven't provided any useful debugging information with which we could help you.